# Angular Directive with model Intercept/filter function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive that wraps [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/)

In all cases, my source data structure is the same, but in one particular scenario I need to alter the data saved back to the server in a dynamic fashion.

My tags are generally in the format `{id: '123', name: 'Some Text'}` but for a particular field in our database, I need to map the data in the following format `{id: 'some-text', name: 'Some Text'}`

Currently I am just updating `ng-model` with the selected tags.

I am thinking of intercepting the selected tag and altering the id from `'123'` to `'some-text'` before updating `ng-model`

**I have created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4CL66i)**

Example

[image: Example of expected data]

I am having trouble working out how to add my interceptor in angular directives

[image: Broken Code]

**Page Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.model = {
    skills: [],
    desired_skills: []
  };

  $scope.dashed = function(value)   {
    var result = _
      .words(value)
      .map(function(x) { return x.toLowerCase(); })
      .join('-');

    //console.log(result);
    return result;
  }

  $scope.intercept = function(item) {
    console.log('item: ' + JSON.stringify(item));

    return { id: $scope.dashed(item.name), name: item.name };
  }

})
```

**Directive Controller**

```
.controller('SkillTagInputController', ['$scope', '$filter', '$q', function($scope, $filter, $q) {


  $scope.loadTags = function (name) {
    return [
      {id: 5, name: "Some Text"},
      {id: 6, name: "More Text"},
      {id: 7, name: "Something Else"}
    ]
  };

}])
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('wkSkillTagInput', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '?ngModel',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        wkOnAddInterceptor: '&'
      },
      template: '<tags-input \
            ng-model="innerModel" \
            ng-change="onChange()" \
            add-on-paste="true" \
            display-property="name" \
            add-from-autocomplete-only="true" \
            replace-spaces-with-dashes="false"> \
                <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)" min-length="2"></auto-complete> \
            </tags-input>',

      controller: 'SkillTagInputController',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if (!ngModel) {
          return;
        }

        // invoked when model changes from the outside
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          scope.innerModel = ngModel.$modelValue;
        };

        // invoked when model changes from the inside
        scope.onChange = function() {
          if (scope.wkOnAddInterceptor) {
            // This is the area I need to get working
            // The intercepter should get called and change the nagure of the selected item
            //ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.$eval(scope.wkOnAddInterceptor));
            ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.innerModel);
          } else {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.innerModel);
          }
        };
      }
    };
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all the main problem is that not exist onChange method in ng-tags-input, you can check the documentation for more information http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api

In this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/x0Kya3xjJIKXLYYTUJR7), i used onTagAdding instead the onChange, the other changes is the way that the interceptor is called. When you pass a function to a directive across the scope, the function always is defined then if you check *if (scope.wkOnAddInterceptor)*  always return true. This is that part of the code:

```
    scope.onTagAdding = function($tag) {
      var tag = scope.wkOnAddInterceptor({item: $tag})
      $tag.id = tag ? tag.id : $tag.id;
      return true;
    }
```

Another error (External to the main question), is that in ngModel.$render, you are assigning the reference of the model, in this case works because you are initializing the model with an empty array:

```
 $scope.model = {
    skills: [],
    desired_skills: []
  };
```

I recommend you to check the model, make a clean copy, and work with the internal methods of ngModelCtrl. This article explain very well the ngModelCtrl flow http://www.chroder.com/2014/02/01/using-ngmodelcontroller-with-custom-directives/

Comment: Thanks Jesús, the tutorial link is brilliant, had trouble with your plunkr, but I have been able to get a working version of what I want here: http://plnkr.co/edit/q17wGk

Comment: You welcome. I'm gonna check the plunkr to fix the errors. Thanks.